# Document scrape using beautifulsoup4.2 and windmill, how to eliminate "document.write();" from the markup passed to BeautifulSoup constructor

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, windmill

I've finally figured out that BS4 no longer uses "markup massaging" as was the case in BS3. But I still need an analogous way to dispose of the unwanted document.write.  You would do the following in BS3, but how to do in BS4?

```
# Javascript code in ths page generates HTML markup  
# that isn't parsed correctly by BeautifulSoup.
# To avoid this problem, all document.write fragments are removed
my_massage = copy(BeautifulSoup.MARKUP_MASSAGE)
my_massage.append((re.compile(u"document.write(.+);"), lambda match: ""))
my_massage.append((re.compile(u'alt=".+">'), lambda match: ">"))
```

Also, since BS4 BeautifulSoup consctuctor no longer supports the markupmassage argument, where in my program should I take care of the document.write problem?  I'm assuming that is the problem because I'm just trying to print out the table markup, and I'm getting a thread exception when I run windmill.

This is what my code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Generated by the windmill services transformer
#from windmill.authoring import WindmillTestClient
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re, urlparse
from copy import copy
from windmill.authoring import setup_module, WindmillTestClient
from windmill.conf import global_settings
import sys


global_settings.START_CHROME = True # This makes it use Firefox
setup_module(sys.modules[__name__])


def get_table_info(client):
        """
    Parse HTML page and extract featured image name and link
    """
    # Get Javascript updated HTML page
    client.waits.forElement(xpath=u"//table[@id='trades']",
                        timeout=40000)
    response = client.commands.getPageText()
    assert response['status']
    assert response['result']

    # Create soup from HTML page and get desired information
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response['result'])

    table_info = soup.select("#trades")
    return table_info


def test_scrape():
    """
    Scrape site
    """

    # Open main gallery page
    client = WindmillTestClient(__name__)
    client.open(url='http://www.zulutrade.com/trader/128391')


    table_info = {}
    table_info = get_table_info(client)


    print table_info



test_scrape()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to tell BeautifulSoup how to massage the markup — you can modify it yourself before feeding it to the `BeautifulSoup` constructor:

```
html = response['result']
html = re.sub(r'document.write(.+);', '', html)
html = re.sub(r'alt=".+">', '>', html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```